# 3D asset toggle options?

Tags: modeling

Total noob here, day 3. I have downloaded a .blend fighter jet into blender. I figured out how to animate and light a little bit. How do you (or how do you know if) toggle the wheels up into the plane for example and close the bay doors?

Im assuming this is possible since a 3D model of a plane with the wheels rigged down only would not make sense for flying animations. The parameters for .obj and .blend files are where? Thank you in advance for any wisdom you can pass down.

Comment: You're asking a very broad question about rigging, animation, blender animation actions, and possibly the non-linear animation editor.  Take a look at [this free model](https://123free3dmodels.com/futuristic-combat-jet-rigged-13657) to an example of a rigged jet.

Comment: is there one obvious way in which to alter the "moving parts" on a 3d object, like an air plane, that allows you to have the wheels retracted into the plane so that it can animate across the sky without looking strange? how do I rig the wheels into the body?

Comment: you can align all the object of the plane with the global axis, parent them to some empties, then rotate and move the empties to correctly place the objects, and at last parent all the empties to the main body of the plane. You'll be able to animate each object (like wheels retracting, doors opening, etc)